# pagekite.py [flying] DynDNS updates may be incomplete, will retry

Tags: tunneling

I am trying to make my localhost:80 available on the internet using [pagekite](https://pagekite.net) with config at `~/.pagekite.rc`:

```
## NOTE: This file may be rewritten/reordered by pagekite.py.
#

##[ Default kite and account details ]##
kitename   = myemail@gmail.com
kitesecret = my_kite_secret

##[ Front-end settings: use pagekite.net defaults ]##
defaults


##[ Back-end service examples ... ]##
#
service_on = https:asldkjdk39090.pagekite.me:localhost:80:my_kite_secret
END
```

I run pagekite:

```
# pagekite.py
>>> Hello! This is pagekite.py v0.5.9.3.                        [CTRL+C = Stop]
    Connecting to front-end relay 54.84.55.54:443 ...
     - Protocols: http http2 http3 https websocket irc finger httpfinger raw
     - Protocols: minecraft
     - Ports: 79 80 443 843 2222 3000 4545 5222 5223 5269 5670 6667 8000 8080
     - Ports: 8081 8082 8083 9292 25565
     - Raw ports: virtual
~<> Flying localhost:80 as https://asldkjdk39090.pagekite.me/
    Trying localhost:80 as https://asldkjdk39090.pagekite.me/
 << pagekite.py [flying]   DynDNS updates may be incomplete, will retry...
```

Then I request `https://asldkjdk39090.pagekite.me/` and it gives an error:

```
$ curl https://asldkjdk39090.pagekite.me/
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: asldkjdk39090.pagekite.me
```

I don't clearly understand why it's not working and how to fix it. I expect that pagekite pass request to my `localhost:80` when I request `https://asldkjdk39090.pagekite.me/` but it doesn't.

## Update

With this config it's working:

```
## NOTE: This file may be rewritten/reordered by pagekite.py.
#

##[ Default kite and account details ]##
kitename   = my_kite_name
kitesecret = my_kite_secret

##[ Front-end settings: use pagekite.net defaults ]##
defaults


##[ Back-end service examples ... ]##
#
service_on = http:my_kite_name.pagekite.me:localhost:80:my_kite_secret
END
```

Where `my_kite_name` is the name I created on [settings](https://pagekite.net/home/#show_pagekites) page.

Then curl https://my_kite_name.pagekite.me/ redirects properly to my localhost

So it's working for pre-created names and not working for a random name like `asldkjdk39090` which I want to use as a subdomain on the fly without registering it on the settings page.

Answer (score 1):

On-the-fly subdomains aren't supported by pagekite.net.

You always have to pre-register, either using the website or the built-in registration tool in `pagekite.py` itself. Unfortunately, on some modern distros the built-in `pagekite.py` registration is currently broken because our API server is obsolete and modern versions of OpenSSL refuse to connect to it.

We are working on fixing that, obviously, but it will take some time because of dependencies.

Comment: what command should be used for preregistering by pagekite.py?

Comment: pagekite.py --add ...

The API server is fixed, so that shoudl work just fine. You can also check https://pagekite.net/home to see what is registered and manage things by hand (you'll then need to hand-edit your pagekite config file as well).

Comment: Check the section at the end of the Quickstart - there is advice on adding/removing kites, and there are links to further documentation: http://pagekite.net/support/quickstart/